# undefined method errors when using libxml's sax parser

Tags: ruby, xml, sax, ruby-1.9, libxml2

I'm trying to use a libxml's SAX parser (as [illustrated here](http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/643/fast-xml-parsing-with-ruby/)), but I'm running into undefined method errors.

My code is

```
$domain_topics = Hash.new { |h,d| h[d] = [] }
parser = LibXML::XML::SaxParser.io(
  File.open("content.rdf.u8", "r:UTF-8")
)
class Callbacks
  include LibXML::XML::SaxParser::Callbacks
  def initialize
    @state = :top
    @topics = nil
  end
  def on_start_element(element, attributes)
    case @state
    when :top
      return unless element == 'ExternalPage'
      @state = :ExternalPage

      domain = attributes['about'].sub(%r!^\w+://([^"/]*)(?:/[^"]*)?$!, '\1')
      @topics = $domain_topics[domain]
    when :ExternalPage
      return unless element == 'topic'
      @state  = :topic
    end
  end
  def on_characters(characters)
    if @state == :topic and @topics
      @topics << characters
    end
  end
  def on_end_element(element)
    case @state
    when :ExternalPage
      @state = :top
      @topics = nil
    when :topic
      @state = :ExternalPage
    end
  end
end
parser.callbacks = Callbacks
parser.parse
```

And when I run it:

```
% ./my_awesome_code.rb
./my_awesome_code.rb:1337:in `parse': undefined method `on_start_document' for Callbacks:Class (NoMethodError)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't `include
LibXML::XML::SaxParser::Callbacks` give a default definition for
`on_start_document`?

irb seems to confirm my intuition:

```
 1.9.3p194 :009 > Callbacks.instance_methods.include? :on_start_document
 => true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am dumb, and missed that `#callbacks=` needs to be passed an *instance* with the proper callbacks, not a class.  So all I needed to do was do

```
parser.callbacks = Callbacks.new
```